# Admob sample code

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm new with android programming and I am interested in Admob. I will use this sample code which I found in internet:

https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/downloads/detail?name=BannerExample_Play_1.0.zip

I tested it and it works properly.
My question is where exactly in this code is the action which detects the clicking on the display and opens the advertisement after clicking the banner?

Answer (score 0):

The type "AdView" have this comportament. You define the atributtes size, id... and it have the event click implicit in your implementation, it is automatic.

Att.